# Windows TaskScheduler - Run locally an executable from a remote server in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch on my C:\TEMP\batch.bat who runs an exe from a remote server (\Remote_host\App_Folder\app.exe)

My .bat content:

```
start /d "\\Remote_host\App_Folder\" app.exe
```

On double click, the batch file runs app.exe correctly. So now, I create a task in Windows Task Scheduler which triggers this batch file.

When task is launched, app.exe is not called.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Pay attention to the account the task runs under, by default it wont be yours and so will likely not have appropriate credentials for the share.

Comment: I've set the task to launch as the user I want but nothing still happen

Comment: Weird, I've checked Run whether user is logged on or not. The checkbox (Do not store password) under this radio button has to be uncheck. Now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task has to run with a specific account and make sure the checkbox "Run whether user is logged on or not." is not checked.

If checked, it will not store the password.